# Class 'Google\Auth\OAuth2' not found

Tags: php, oauth, google-plus-signin

I was trying to add google plus login to my web but I encountered this error which seems really weird because I have the file already added. I already enable vendor/autoload (Im using codeigniter)

Anyone had this kind of error before? How did you fix this?

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Class 'Google\Auth\OAuth2' not found

Filename: Google/Client.php

Line Number: 929

Backtrace:
```

Comment: I assume you are using this package https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client. Did you install it via composer? It has several dependencies and it looks like based on the error, that you may be missing some of them.

Comment: @Mark hi, yes your right, I did not realize that there are also autoload files inside the google package,,

Comment: Great, let me post the comment as an answer then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using [this](http://github.com/google/google-api-php-client) package. Did you install it via `composer`? It has several dependencies and it looks like based on the error, that you may be missing some of them.